# Como gerar o arquivo jar com comandos do maven?

Tags: maven

Estou num projeto Spring Boot, eu estou conseguindo gerar o arquivo jar através da ferramenta do eclipse como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 Etapa;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 Etapa;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ultima;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando eu executo através do maven ele gera vários erros como podem ver abaixo;

```
  mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\re038022\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.3.0.RELEASE\dockerTest\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

DESKTOP-LTE4439+resource@DESKTOP-LTE4439 MINGW64 /c/Users/re038022/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.3.0.RELEASE/dockerTest

$  mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\re038022\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.3.0.RELEASE\dockerTest\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Eu já tentei com  **mvn clean install** e também não funcionou, não sei o que pode haver de errado, preciso de ajuda.

Esse é meu arquivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dockerTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>mysql</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> -->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Migracoes - Flyway -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Java 8 Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Suporte do Jackson para as datas do Java 8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Eu preciso conseguir gerar o arquivo Jar através do comandos do maven. É muito importante que eu consigar fazer através de comandos!

Pelo erro está dizendo que o problema está na linha 5 do arquivo pom.xml que se refere a esse trecho de código;

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Percebi que você está usando um settings específico quando gera pelo Eclipse

Por linha de comando talvez você esteja usando outro

Inicialmente verifique se o java que é chamado por linha de comando é o mesmo que você chama no Eclipse (execute no prompt do DOS)

```
java -version
```

Depois verifique se é o mesmo Maven

```
mvn -version
```

Por fim garanta que você está usando o settings.xml correto

```
 mvn --settings C:\Users\re038022\settings.xml clean install
```

Se não der erro o jar deve ser gerado na pasta target com o clean install

Se mesmo assim der erro execute o mesmo comando passando o argumento -X para ver informações de debug

```
mvn -X --settings C:\Users\re038022\settings.xml clean install
```

Comment: não existe nenhum arquivo settings.xml na pasta do re038022

Comment: acredito que você deva estar usando a vesão embarcada do maven no eclipse, você chegou a instalar o maven "por fora"??

Comment: instalei sim, e tanto que consigo executar os comandos do maven em qualquer lugar do MSDOS.

Comment: o comando não funcionou mesmo realizando no arquivo certo onde se encontra o setteings.xml 'mvn --settings C:\Users\re038022\settings.xml clean install'

Comment: verifique a configuração do proxy no settings.xml como o Jroger mencionou, talvez você esteja usando uma configuração de proxy diferente no Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Não existe erro na sua configuração, antes de empacotar, primeiro vc precisa resolver o problema de dependência do seu pom. No log está dizendo que o maven não conseguiu obter a dependência:

> [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.example:dockerTest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal
>   alert: protocol_version and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local
>   POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Buscando no [mavenrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.3.RELEASE) ela existe, logo pode ser um problema para fazer download da dependência e nada mais, verifique seu proxy e se for autenticado configure o maven para autenticar.

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent

Outra coisa é que o uso do `relativePath` costuma gerar erros na saída e podem ser interpretados como falso-positivos ( não é o seu caso ), segue como informação da documentação de como o `relativePath` funciona:

> The relative path of the parent pom.xml file within the check out. If
>   not specified, it defaults to ../pom.xml. Maven looks for the parent
>   POM first in this location on the filesystem, then the local
>   repository, and lastly in the remote repo. relativePath allows you to
>   select a different location, for example when your structure is flat,
>   or deeper without an intermediate parent POM. However, the group ID,
>   artifact ID and version are still required, and must match the file in
>   the location given or it will revert to the repository for the POM.
>   This feature is only for enhancing the development in a local checkout
>   of that project. Set the value to an empty string in case you want to
>   disable the feature and always resolve the parent POM from the
>   repositories.

Uma opção é executar o `package` usando a opção `-X` que habilita o debug no log:

`mvn clean package -X`

Comment: Se eu for executar esse comando 'maven clean package -X' o maven não reconhece 'bash: maven: command not found'

Comment: Desculpa, foi um erro de sintaxe o comando seria `mvn clean package -X`